# Address individual cells in a one dimensional range

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to address individual cells in a one dimensional range. In this case I want the range object `OneDimRange` to point to the second cell in a one dimensional range:

```
Dim OneDimRange as Range
Dim SingleCellRange as Range

Set OneDimRange = Range("B5:B15")
x = 2 'should be B6

'THOSE NOTATIONS DON'T WORK:
Set SingleCellRange = OneDimRange.Cells(x,1)
Set SingleCellRange = OneDimRange.Cells(x,0)
Set SingleCellRange = OneDimRange.Cells(x)
```

What exactly is the notation for a one dimensional range?

Comment: To prove that you're wrong on two accounts, try the following line after each of the `Set` lines: `Debug.Print SingleCellRange.Address(0, 0)` and look in the Immediate window (CTRL+G) for the results.

Comment: `Set SingleCellRange = OneDimRange.Cells(x, 1):Debug.Print SingleCellRange.Address` returns `$B$6`

Comment: How exactly did you determine they  "don't work" ?  FYI `Cells()` is one-based (for numeric arguments) and can be given either one or two arguments (numeric, then optional numeric/string).  Worth noting that you can index *outside* of the Range and Excel will not complain as long as the result is a valid range, so `Range("A1").Cells(2, 2)` is B2 for example.

Comment: @all thanks for your comments, turns out that it was a problem with Excel, restarting the application helped. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You might want to have a look at the documentation for [Range.Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.item) and maybe also of [Range.Cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.cells). These explain rather clearly how the indexing works and show why your last version actually always works for one-dimensional ranges.

Comment: @all feel free if anyone would like to post an answer, otherwise I'll do it.